# How do I make my logo button appear in the middle of a header element

Tags: html, css

Hey i'm trying to make my logo appear in the middle of a header element I don't know what else to try. (The button I wont to make appear in the middle is the third list item and the class name is logobutton. Ive tried to use text-align and nothing changes. The only thing that changes is when I use float but float doesn't have a center option. I tried to style  with text-align:center but that centers the whole list.)

```css
header {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #DC143C;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px; 
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black; 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: TransFormers;
  src: url('fonts/Transformers Movie.ttf') format('truetype');
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a-nav-top:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0      rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li a.button {
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
  color: #DC143C;
  width: 10%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

li a.logobutton {
  font-family: TransFormers;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a class="logobutton" href="#">RG</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the `position` property on the parent `ul` and the child `li`, and use the `calc()` value to define the `left` property of the child `li`:

```css
ul {
  _position: relative; /* added; first example */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* first example */
ul > li:last-child { /* could also use :nth-child(3) */
  _position: absolute; /* added */
  _left: calc(50% - 11.1px); /* half of the header width - half of the logo width */
}
/*****/

/* second example */
ul {
  display: flex; /* added */
  justify-content: space-between; /* added */
}
/*****/

header {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #DC143C;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px; 
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black; 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: TransFormers;
  src: url('fonts/Transformers Movie.ttf') format('truetype');
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a-nav-top:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0      rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li a.button {
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
  color: #DC143C;
  width: 10%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

li a.logobutton {
  font-family: TransFormers;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header> 
  <ul>
    <div>
      <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Home1</a></li>
      <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Shop1</a></li>
    </div>
    <li><a class="logobutton" href="#">RG</a></li>
    <div>
      <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Home2</a></li>
      <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Shop2</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `position: absolute` property on your `.logobutton` element and apply zero values to `top, bottom, left & right` properties to make it center align (since its an anchor tag, you need to also provide `display: block` for it to behave like a block level element.

Also, provide a `position: relative` to the parent `ul`.

Refer code:

```css
header {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #DC143C;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: TransFormers;
  src: url('fonts/Transformers Movie.ttf') format('truetype');
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a-nav-top:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li a.button {
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
  color: #DC143C;
  width: 10%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

li a.logobutton {
  font-family: TransFormers;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="a a-nav-top button" href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a class="logobutton" href="#">RG</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```